# extract ip address of eth0 from a telnet session

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I need to automate a process that works with a remote device,

Here are the steps

1. telnet
2. enter username
3. ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1
4. write down the shown ip and do the rest of the process with that ip address.

The known ip is the telnet_ip and i want to retrieve the ip address that I can ssh into.

I want to automate these four steps into a function called `get_ip` that echos out the ip address. I would like to use this function as follows

```
SSH_IP=$(get_ip 127.0.0.1 1000)
```

I looked around and I see that a possibility is to use `expect`. I have written this function

```
function get_ip(){
expect << EOF
spawn telnet $1 $2
expect -ex "Escape character is '^]'."
send  "\r"
expect {
    -re ".*login: " {
        send "root\r"
    }
}
expect -re ".*root:~# "
send "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1\r"
expect eof
send "\x1b\r"
expect "telnet>"
send "q\r"
puts "Address is $IPADDR"
EOF
}
```

Running this function, I see the ip address on screen but it is not captured in the variable `SSH_IP`.

I need help in two areas:
1. What do I do so that `SSH_IP` contains the ip address. 
2. How could I make `expect` do all of this silently and return the result?

Please tel me if there is any other way to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Side note - `eth0` has been going away for some time, so hardcoding that seems ... optimistic. That command returns blank on my Linux box, both because eth0 doesn't exist, and because `inet addr` doesn't appear in the output if I pick an existing interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the areas where expect is a PITA: capturing command output. You'll want to do this:

```
function get_ip(){

    # pass the shell function params via the environment, so we can quote the expect script
    host=$1 port=$2 expect << 'EOF'

        # use `log_user` and `spawn -noecho` to stop output to stdout
        log_user 0
        spawn -noecho telnet $env(host) $env(port)

        expect -ex "Escape character is '^]'."
        send  "\r"
        expect "login: "
        send "root\r"
        expect "root:~# "

        send "ifconfig eth0\r"      # expect can parse the output, don't need a pipeline
        expect -re "(.*)root:~# "   # note the captured part
        set ip_addr [regexp -inline {inet addr:(\S+)} $expect_out(1,string)]
        puts "Address is $ip_addr"

        send "\x1b\r"
        expect "telnet>"
        send "q\r"

        # NOW you expect eof
        expect eof

EOF
}
```

We could even use the expect pattern to capture it:

```
        send "ifconfig eth0\r"
        expect -re ".*inet addr:(\S+).*root:~# "
        puts "Address is $expect_out(1,string)"
```

Tcl command documentation: https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm

Comment: thank you for the answer but this still give me an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with `tmux` instead of `expect`. Here is my solution

```
#! /bin/env bash
WINDOW_NAME=TELNET
DEBUG=
function dbbg(){
    [[ "$DEBUG" ]] && echo "DEBUG: $@"
}

function cleanup(){
    [[ "$DEBUG" ]] || tmux kill-window -t ${WINDOW_NAME} > /dev/null 2>&1
}

trap cleanup EXIT

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Usage $(basename $0) <telnet ip> <telnet port>"
    exit 0
fi

# Start the work with sessions
tmux has-session 2>/dev/null
if [ "$?" -eq 1 ]
then
    dbbg "No Session found.  Creating and configuring."

    tmux new-session -d
else
    dbbg "Session found."
fi
tmux has-session -t :${WINDOW_NAME} 2>/dev/null
if [ "$?" -eq 1 ]
then
    dbbg "No window found. Creating a window named ${WINDOW_NAME}"

    tmux new-window -d -n ${WINDOW_NAME}
else
    dbbg "Window found."
fi

dbbg "connecting to tmux ip: $1 port: $2"
tmux send-keys -t :${WINDOW_NAME} "telnet $1 $2" Enter
sleep 2

answer="$(tmux capture-pane -t :${WINDOW_NAME} -p | sed '/^$/d' | tail -n 1)"
dbbg $answer
if [ "$answer" != "Escape character is '^]'." ] 
then
    echo "Telnet is occupied at the moment, try later"
    exit 1
fi

tmux send-keys -t :${WINDOW_NAME} Enter
sleep 2
answer="$(tmux capture-pane -t :${WINDOW_NAME} -p | sed '/^$/d' | tail -n 1)"
dbbg $answer
if [ "$answer" == "login:" ] 
then
    dbbg "Inputing user"
    tmux send-keys -t :${WINDOW_NAME} "root" Enter
    sleep 2
fi
tmux send-keys -t :${WINDOW_NAME} "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1" Enter
sleep 2

ip_addr="$(tmux capture-pane -t :${WINDOW_NAME} -p | sed '/^$/d' | tail -n 2 | head -n 1)"

tmux send-keys -t :${WINDOW_NAME} C-]
sleep 2
tmux send-keys -t :${WINDOW_NAME} "q" Enter
echo $ip_addr
```